# why does oracle apex 4.2.4 show the text 'body p' in border of rich textarea when the textarea is clicked

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In Oracle Application Express version 4.2.4 when you click in a textarea box that is created using rich text with the CKEditor 3 you will see the text "body p" appear in the bottom grey border area.
When you first land on the page that has the rich textarea you do not see the text.  Only when you click in the textarea does the unwanted text show in the bottom left border.

Changing to rich text with the FCKEditor 2 alleviates the problem.  Is this fixable somehow.  If so please give the steps to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "plugin" called elementspath. You can remove it from an instance of the editor with code like this:

CKEDITOR.appendTo('container', {
    removePlugins: 'elementspath' 
});

Or you can edit the config.js file to remove it from all instances.

config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
config.resize_enabled = false;